# Why can't I import "white" color from Material UI colors?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to convert a Material UI icon to white because background is another color.

I am importing white from their core colors library:

```
import { white } from '@material-ui/core/colors';
```

So I can do:

```
style={{ color: white }}
```

However, I am getting an error message:

```
./src/components/footer.js
Attempted import error: 'white' is not exported from '@material-ui/core/colors'.
```

I cannot see what I am doing wrong based on their [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#color). I have throughly researched why I am getting this error but couldn't find solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check available color palette from MaterialUI [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/color/)

White is not available.

But you can use `'white'` as string, as CSS has 'white' as value

```js
style={{ color: 'white' }}
```

A complete list of colors supported by CSS can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp)

Comment: Makes sense! Who needs white nowadays anyway?

Comment: Maybe their reasoning was white and black are objective colors so they don't need to be imported.

Answer (score 6):

A good approach is what @Sabbin suggested. But if you want a typed object from MaterialUI, it's available in the `theme`. You can find more about this in the [theme explorer in the documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/?expand-path=$.palette.common.white).

For example:

```
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  
  const whiteColor = theme.palette.common.white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list of the colors that you can import from material-ui:

```
export { default as amber } from './amber';
export { default as blue } from './blue';
export { default as blueGrey } from './blueGrey';
export { default as brown } from './brown';
export { default as common } from './common';
export { default as cyan } from './cyan';
export { default as deepOrange } from './deepOrange';
export { default as deepPurple } from './deepPurple';
export { default as green } from './green';
export { default as grey } from './grey';
export { default as indigo } from './indigo';
export { default as lightBlue } from './lightBlue';
export { default as lightGreen } from './lightGreen';
export { default as lime } from './lime';
export { default as orange } from './orange';
export { default as pink } from './pink';
export { default as purple } from './purple';
export { default as red } from './red';
export { default as teal } from './teal';
export { default as yellow } from './yellow';
```

> Source is the file `core/colors/index.d.ts`

As you can see in the list, white is not there, so you can't import it.

If you need a color other than the ones in the list above, you can just use it directly without importing it as:

- a named-color, eg. [`"white"`, `"red"`, ...]
- an rgb color, eg. [`rgb(0, 50, 150)`]
- a hex color, eg. [`#fe56fe`]

Answer (score 2):

Here is official solution from official documentation

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
 palette: {
  primary: {
   light: '#757ce8',
   main: '#3f50b5',
   dark: '#002884',
   contrastText: '#fff',
           },
secondary: {
  light: '#ff7961',
  main: '#ffffff',
  dark: '#ba000d',
  contrastText: '#000',
           },
          },
         });
```

You can change main color from primary and set it to 'ffffff'

Answer (score 0):

You should import it from the `common` file

```
import white from '@material-ui/core/colors/common';
```

Comment: This type of import is [not allowed](https://mui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-1) with material ui. From the docs:  _Be aware that we only support first and second-level imports. Anything deeper is considered private and can cause issues, such as module duplication in your bundle._ Given such a warning, you should instead do: `import {common} from '@mui/material/colors'` (assuming mui 5), then use `common.white` or `common.black`